# Fill block height = 100% in a row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How is possible to fill-in the height of a row with a cell in the following >>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/serhiol/fnr2vy74/):

```css
.x                    { height: 50px;          }
.row                  { background: #eee;      }
.row>:nth-child(odd)  { background: lightblue; }
.row>:nth-child(even) { background: pink;      }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">fill height v</div>
  <div class="col-xs-9"> <div class="x"> unknown height </div> </div>
</div>
```

**PS.** in order to be mobile compatible and also IE 11, I can't use `flex`

Comment: you can't do this with float property

Comment: this is why I am asking here :)

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: I prefeer a pure CSS solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `.row{display: flex}`

```css
.x {  height: 50px; }
.row {background: #eee; display: flex;}
.row>:nth-child(odd) {
  background: lightblue;
}

.row>:nth-child(even) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3 cell">fill height v</div>
  <div class="col-xs-9 cell">
    <div class="x"> unknown height </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

width absolute position `jsfiddle.net/kth9vqhf`

with display: table `jsfiddle.net/kth9vqhf/1`

with jQuery `https://jsfiddle.net/kth9vqhf/3/`

Comment: is there any other sugestions than flex?

Comment: position: absolute for first block; and padding-left for parent: 'your block width'

Comment: good work... please keep all variants in your answer  for other people ! thanks

Comment: @Serge  no problem bro)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can calculate the height of `.x` on the fly and set that as the minimum height for the cell.

```js
$('.col-xs-3.cell').css("min-height", $('.x').height() + "px");
```

```css
.x {
  height: 50px;
}

.row {
  background: #eee;
}

.row>:nth-child(odd) {
  background: lightblue;
}

.row>:nth-child(even) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3 cell">fill height v</div>
  <div class="col-xs-9 cell">
    <div class="x"> unknown height </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fill Row Height </title>
    <style>
        .WrapperRow{float: left; display: table; table-layout:  fixed; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;}
        .WrapperRow > div{display: table-cell; float: none; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px;}
        .bgblue{background-color: blue;}
        .cell.bgblue{width: 30%;}
        .bgpink{background-color: pink;}
    </style>    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="WrapperRow">
        <div class="cell bgblue">
        </div>
        <div class="cell bgpink">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In ipsa natus, vel non earum, distinctio iusto reprehenderit alias quisquam possimus, at qui nostrum ad enim totam repudiandae consectetur eius iste? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum illum, aut sunt molestias tempora amet maxime ipsum? Vero animi beatae, dicta? Ut repudiandae fugit alias quasi esse culpa. Facere, dolore?
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, but a lot of details like vertical align, width 30% padding: 10px not asked and cofusing...

Comment: See dude,
This is just for reference..
Just make an html file copy my code...
Everything will be cleared....
width: 30%; means first div will get 30% width;;
With css & Other one will automatically get 70% due to table-layout fixed....
view more for table layout fixed on google 
padding just given for proper typography here...
you no need to give...
Give accordingly u need..
in table layout 
height will be same for display:  table-cell, 
divs...